# There is no link to page 6 on page 4

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, pagination

Seems inconsistent:

```
prev 1 .. 5 6 [7] 8 9 .. 390331 next
prev 1 .. 4 5 [6] 7 8 .. 390331 next
prev 1 .. 3 4 [5] 6 7 .. 390331 next
prev 1    2 3 [4] 5 .. 390331 next
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I think it's by design, not a bug. However, [there's also no link to page `1416 - 2` on page `1416`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kL9eP.png).

Comment: @KevinGuan "four nearest pages + first + last" is the rule I've thought of, I just don't see any reason not to follow it on some pages.

Comment: No repro in ie6 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg

Comment: How often are specific pages linked to? Don't they change so fast it's really irrelevant? Why not just have first/prev/next/last with a page indicator? At least for the questions list that seems workable, though I'm one of those weirdos who likes infinite scrolling (let me scroll until I get bored).

Comment: Helps save bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

Since we always have a link to the first page, and we always show *5* adjacent pages, this is, in fact, consistent.

There is no gap between page 1 and 2, so to show the 5 adjacent pages, we go up to 5 when on page 4.

Comment: Okay, I understand. It is just weird that you can leap two pages from anywhere but one page.

Comment: @Leonid two pages really as you will see the same issue when you are are 3 pages away from the end.

Comment: Hm... from a certain point of view, it is consistent. Still, the rule is confusing and complicated. Showing a link to the first and last page, as well as to all pages two before to two after the current page, eliminate duplicates, that would be simpler and more useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator what do you do for pages 1, 2, last, last -1?

Comment: @JoeW I think the idea is as follows: If n <= 6, show all pages. For i=1 to 3, show 1 to 5 and last. For i=n-2 to n, show 1 and n-4 to n. Otherwise, show 1, i-2 to i+2, and n.

Comment: @DamianYerrick now could you write that in Lisp? Having trouble following...

Comment: @Qix `(insert-dots (remove-duplicates (merge (list-n-nearest-between 4 page 1 total) (list 1 total))))`